# Find the absolute maximum and minimum of $f(x,y) = 1-xy$ in the domain $x^2+y^2 \le 2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

My exam is tomorrow and I can't figure this out. I tried using Lagrange and it doesn't seem to work (I'm left with an unsolvable system of equations)

Comment: Here is something you **really** need to understand if you have an exam on this stuff: the method of Lagrange multipliers applies to maximising/minimising a function subject to an "equality constraint", that is, there is a condition of the form $g(x,y)=c$.  In this case you have an "inequality constraint" $g(x,y)\le c$, so Lagrange is not the way to go.  (Though as part of the problem, you might want to maximise/minimise $f$ when $x^2+y^2=2$, and for this part you could use Lagrange.  However it still won't solve the whole problem.)

Comment: In other words, Lagrange is only to find maximum/minimum values on the bounds of the domain and not inside?

Comment: You still need lagrange multipliers (or something similar) to check the edge conditions.  The min/maximum could be at a critical point or at an edge.

Comment: @DanielV True, though Momo's answer handles the boundary and interior with the same working.

Answer (score 1):

I would use polar coordinates $x=r\cos t$, $y=r\sin t$

Your problem can be rewritten as maximize/minimize $f(r,t)=1-r^2\sin t\cos t=1-\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin 2t$ with $0<r<\sqrt 2$ and $0\le t< 2\pi$

The maximum is $2$ is attained when $r=\sqrt 2$ and $2t=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi$, and the minimum is $0$ and is attained when $r=\sqrt 2$ and $2t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi$

Comment: I've only used polar coordinates to compute integrals. I understand the switch to polar coordinates (very good idea), but how did you get the max/min from the polar equation?

Comment: $f$ attains minimum when $r^2\sin 2t$ is maximum, which happens when both $r^2$ and $\sin 2t$ attain their maximum allowed values of $2$ respectively $1$. The minimum is similar. You will get two points of max and two points of min.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is easy enough to not have to invoke Lagrange. Fix a point $(x_0,y_0)$ in $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq2\}$ with non-negative first coordinate and observe that for $\varepsilon\geq0$
$$
1-x_0(y_0+\varepsilon)\leq1-x_0y_0\leq1-x_0(y_0-\varepsilon).
$$
Translated in terms of $f$ this tells you that both the maximum and minimum of $f$ in $D\cap\{(x,y):x\geq0\}$ are attained (particularly) in the circle $\partial D$. The same reasoning (with reversed inequalities in the above estimates) can be made for a point with negative first coordinate, allowing us to conclude that the maximum and minimum of $f$ in $D$ are attained in the circle $\partial D$. This reduces the problem to find the maximum and minimum of
$$
f(\sqrt{2}\cos\theta,\sqrt2\sin\theta)=1-2\cos\theta\sin\theta,\,\,\,\,\theta\in[0,2\pi),
$$
which I leave to you.

Answer (score 0):

First you should calculate $\nabla f(x,y)=(-y,-x)=(0,0)$. So $(0,0)$ is the  minimum, now you have to use lagrande multiplier to the constraint $x^2+y^2=2$ using $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2$

Comment: I tried using Lagrange with that constraint but ended up with an unsolvable system of equations :(

Comment: Why is the system unsolvable?

Comment: I get $-y-2x\Lambda=0$, $-x-2y\Lambda=0$ and $-x^2-y^2=2$ and no matter how I approach it, I can't solve it.

Comment: That is not unsolvable. Try to find values for lamba, example $y=4y\lambda^2$ so $\lambda=1/2$

Comment: Note that in Lagrange multiplier problems it is essential to find all solutions of the equations.  The solution of $y=4y\lambda^2$ is $\lambda=\frac12$ or $y=0$, not just $\lambda=\frac12$.  In this problem $y=0$ will not give a maximum or minimum, but sometimes it will, so you need to check just in case.

Comment: @Dat8StringGuy Easy way to solve your equations: $y$ times the first minus $x$ times the second gives $x^2-y^2=0$, then combine this with $x^2+y^2=2$.  (Note it is not $-x^2-y^2=2$, I don't know how you got that.)